# Xelatex, set papersize FROM CMD(!)

Tags: xetex, paper-size

Can I set paper size from command line?
F.e.

```
xelatex -papersize=a5 -jobname=kafka_A5 kafka.tex
```

But in my case, the effect only applies to the first page. And while it is cut off.[image]

Begin of document

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, twoside, 10pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{fontspec}                     %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

% -------------- Настраваем шрифты -----------------------------
\setmainfont[StylisticSet=1]{Kurale}% Основной шрифт текста
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

% ================ Настройка некоторых параметров =================|
\parindent=25pt %------------------------------Отступ первой строки|
% -----------------------------------------------------------------|

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\tolerance=1070
```

Comment: Please don't shout. People can hear perfectly well if you speak normally.

Comment: Please can you make your example compilable? People can't reproduce the problem with this. Do note that changing the paper size will not change the logical layout of the page by itself. So if you just change the paper, you'll have A4 layout or US letter layout on A5 paper, which obviously won't fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xelatex "\PassOptionsToClass{a5paper}{book} \input{kafka}"
```

change `book` to your own used documentclass

Comment: If I understand "-papersize" deprecated?

Comment: I'm afraid, but that does not change anything. Outsize is a4.

Comment: do you have package geometry loaded?

Comment: yes I have package geometry loaded

Comment: Would this prepend or append the option? Because, for it to work with the example shown (insofar as it is shown at all), it would have to be appended rather than prepended, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Игорь: It makes no sense to use the `a4paper` in the documentclass and then print it at a5. I suppose that `a4paper` is already the default, so you do not need it. And then it should work with

Comment: @Herbert, Those. the document should use "\ documentclass [openright, twoside, 12pt] {extreport}" without specifying the page size?

Comment: @Игорь yes. It is done by `\PassOptionsToClass{a5paper}{extreport}`. Or as an alternative: `\PassOptionsToPackage{a5paper}{geometry}`